# Meteor absoluteUrl issue

Tags: url, meteor

I have read dozens of posts about absoluteUrl but still cannot get a clear understanding. 
I want to use multiple apps point to the same server code base. Each app has an appId (for example: http://localhost:3000/app1). Based on this id, server will serve corresponding assets to that app.

On client code, I have:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log('client startup');  
    Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = "http://localhost:3000/app1";   
    console.log(Meteor.absoluteUrl()); 
    //this line prints out http://localhost:3000/app1
});
```

and then:

```
meteor run ios
```

However, on simulator, my app is empty/blank, because it still points to `localhost:3000` i think, while i only have router for '`:_appId`'.

I also tried `ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000/app1 meteor run ios`, but it also does not work.

My intention is to bundle different app with different rootURL (/app2, /app3, ..) but use the same server code base. How could I do that?

Thank you.